# Second-order matrix equations

Tags: matrix-equations, control-theory, generalized-eigenvector

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times n}$ and $D\in\mathbb{R}^{q\times p}$ be known matrices. Denote by $I_n$ the identity matrix of size $n\times n$ and $0_n$ the zero column vector of size $n$. My problem is to solve the second-order matrix equations $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
                               zI_{n}-A & -B \\
                               C & D \\
                             \end{array}
                           \right]v=0_{n+q}$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+p}$ are unknowns. Is there any algorithm that can obtain the solution set of this second-order matrix equation problem?

Comment: Why do you refer to this as second order?

Comment: This is a generalised eigenvalue problem. Look at `qz` in Matlab.

Comment: @ copper.hat The problem is that $z$ is also an unknown, so I think it is second order.

Comment: It is no more second order than an eigenvalue problem. It doesn't matter, I was just wondering why.